# Questions about functions

Tags: function

True    or  False:  When    a   function    is  called, the calling program suspends    until
the function    completes.

True    or  False:  When    you call    a   function    with    a   list    as  a   parameter,  you could
change  the original    calling program’s   list    from    within  the function

True    or  False:  When     you    call    a   function    with    a   dictionary  as  a   parameter,  you could   change  the original    calling program’s   dictionary  from    within  the 
function.

Im very fuzzy on these questions and what they mean, could someone help explain these?

Comment: True or false: You are asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: it's not howework site.

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you posted your answers along with your rationale.

Answer (score 0):

1.True
the original program will stop and going to run the function. It will back to the place where it stop and start to execute the next line command after function done.

2.False
call by value. it wont change the original variable's value.

3.True
call by pointer or call by reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometime yes and sometimes no. It depends whether you are calling it synchronously or asynchronously, see this answer for the distinction: [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)
2. In most cases yes, because you are just passing by reference, i.e you are passing the location in memory of the param you are passing. However, you can also pass by value, i.e passing a copy of the object. See this question for more detail: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
3. same answer as your previous question. Whether you are passing an integer, string, array, list, dictionary, it doesn't matter, it all depends on whether you are passing by reference or by value. Which one of these happens by default depends on which programming language you use. You can determine which one is happening pretty easily with some experimentation: Define a function with a dictionary variable, add a key/value pair call another function with the dict as a param, and modify it in the called function, then print it out in the calling function once the called function has returned. If it has been modified, you know you are passing by reference. If it has the original key/value you set in the caller and is not modified, you know you are passing by value.